# Copy function exactly, errors anyway

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to plot indicators on a graph with quantmod. I have a few adjustments I want to make to the bbands function, but even if I copy the function exactly, I still get an error. Here were my steps:

1. type "addBBands"
2. control + c the code
3. type addBBands2 <- {copied code}

when trying to use the function this happens

```
Error in addBBands2() : could not find function "get.current.chob"
```

Here is the code

```
addBBands2<- function (n = 20, sd = 2, maType = "SMA", draw = "bands", on = -1) 
function (n = 20, sd = 2, maType = "SMA", draw = "bands", on = -1) 
{
    stopifnot("package:TTR" %in% search() || require("TTR", quietly = TRUE))
    draw.options <- c("bands", "percent", "width")
    draw <- draw.options[pmatch(draw, draw.options)]
    lchob <- get.current.chob()
    x <- as.matrix(lchob@xdata)
    chobTA <- new("chobTA")
    if (draw == "bands") {
        chobTA@new <- FALSE
    }
    else {
        chobTA@new <- TRUE
        on <- NULL
    }
    xx <- if (is.OHLC(x)) {
        cbind(Hi(x), Lo(x), Cl(x))
    }
    else x
    bb <- BBands(xx, n = n, maType = maType, sd = sd)
    chobTA@TA.values <- bb[lchob@xsubset, ]
    chobTA@name <- "chartBBands"
    chobTA@call <- match.call()
    chobTA@on <- on
    chobTA@params <- list(xrange = lchob@xrange, colors = lchob@colors, 
        color.vol = lchob@color.vol, multi.col = lchob@multi.col, 
        spacing = lchob@spacing, width = lchob@width, bp = lchob@bp, 
        x.labels = lchob@x.labels, time.scale = lchob@time.scale, 
        n = n, ma = maType, sd = sd, draw = draw)
    return(chobTA)
}
```

They aren't identical though somehow,

```
> str(addBBands)
function (n = 20, sd = 2, maType = "SMA", draw = "bands", on = -1)  
> str(addBBands2)
function (n = 20, sd = 2, maType = "SMA", draw = "bands", on = -1)  
 - attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 14 31 1 14 1 1 31
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x25eb9bf4>
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use `newTA` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know quantmod, but presumably this is because `get.current.chob` is not exported from the package namespace. You could try referencing it with `quantmod:::get.current.chob`. There will probably be many such errors for other non-exported functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the function has the correct `environment` set so it can see non-exported functions.

Either copy the function (which will keep the environment):

```
addBBands2 <- addBBands
```

and then `edit` that.

Or change the `environment` directly after creating a new function. Consider:

```
f <- function() get.current.chob()
f()
Error in f() : could not find function "get.current.chob"
environment(f) <- environment(addBBands)
f()
An object of class "chob"
Slot "device":
...
```